# Installing mongodb when deploying express application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

finally, i am so happy because im about to deploy my first express app yey!

i choose heroku and already follow step by step guidance to deploy nodejs application but none of those steps shows me how to import database because at this moment i am coding my express app in my laptop with mongodb installed, i expect in heroku there is mongodb then i can import my mongodb data to it as i do it in PHP + mysql. i have read some articles on google but still confuse.

> to sum up my question :
>
> 1. Where should i store my documents on mongodb when deploy ?
> 2. Please give us some recommended tips to deploy express app with mongodb.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For importing database ,you have to use mlab (mLab's MongoDB hosting platform is the fastest growing cloud Database-as-a-Service in the world).
https://mlab.com/ , just change the address in your app from local db to mlab db.

Comment: The other alternative is that you have to set address of your db
like this 
mongo://<user>:<pass>@<host_name or ip_address>:<port>/<collection_name>

for this you have to open the port no.